# Cmp conflicts with native autocomplete i_CTRL-P and i_CTRL-N

Tags: neovim, autocompletion

I use `lsp-zero.nvim` and it requires `nvim-cmp` which is what I think is causing the problem.

How can I retain the native autocompletion `i_CTRL-P` and `i_CTRL-N` while also using `cmp`?

Comment: ask over at the [plugins issue tracker](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [zero-lsp.nvim](https://github.com/VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim) comes with some default key bindings that overrides the standard <kbd>Ctrl n</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl p</kbd>.

You can disable these key bindings following the instruction: [disable keybindings](https://github.com/VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim/blob/v2.x/doc/md/lsp.md#disable-keybindings)

The default setup instruction propose to add the following code into `init.lua`:

```lua
local lsp = require('lsp-zero').preset({})

lsp.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
  -- see :help lsp-zero-keybindings
  -- to learn the available actions
  lsp.default_keymaps({buffer = bufnr})
end)

lsp.setup()
```

If you don't want to override the key bindings insert instead:

```lua
local lsp = require('lsp-zero').preset({})

lsp.setup()
```

Comment: This _feels_ like a link-only answer. Could you elaborate and add the necessary instructions?